# How to add drill-down jQuery datatable in salesforce

Tags: visualforce, jquery, datatable

I have a requirement Where I need to create a data table in visualforce using jQuery with a expansion / Drill- down button. If i click on the expansion button it should expand the row and show other information.

Here is an example...
http://datatables.net/blog/Drill-down_rows. I need to implement this in visualforce.

Please help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Well datatables is a jQuery plugin there is no specific guide on how to implement the same in VF pages or Force.com. You can go through the documentation and can implement the same using datatables API. You can have a look at JS remoting to bring the data to VF pages.

Answer (score 1):

I know how to play with expand and collapes of section which are generally use in Visualforce page then below links help you.

1)http://www.forcetree.com/2010/04/expand-collapse-pageblock-table-columns.html

2)http://salesforce-stuff.blogspot.in/2011/11/collapse-pageblocksection.html

you can open a iframe where you can show info by sending the id of record when user expand the section

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this, look at this blog it is exactly what you need.
http://macscloud.com/dynamic-datatables-with-jquery-and-visualforce/

Site appears to be offline

Comment: Your link is dead.